# Extension field exercise doubt

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

I want to prove that if  $X^{n}-a\in K[X]$ is irreducible and $\beta$ is a root of $X^{n}-a$ in one extension of $K$ and $m$ divides $n$ then
$\left[K\left(\beta^{m}\right):K\right]=n/m$. I want to calculate the irreducible polynomial of degree $n/m$ if possible, because maybe with that it would be easier to conclude that $\left[K\left(\beta^{m}\right):K\right]=n/m$

I've managed to do the following...

If $\beta$ is a root of $X^{n}-a\Rightarrow$ $\beta^{n}=a$ in its extension. Considering the fact that $m|n$ then $n=m\cdot t$. Thus $\left(\beta^{m}\right)^{t}=\beta^{n}=a$ and $\beta^{m}$ is a root of $X^{t}-a$. In conclusion, $\left[K\left(\beta^{m}\right):K\right]\leq t=n/m$ but I don't know how to prove the other inequality. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can show that $\big[K(\beta):K(\beta^m)\big]\leq m$.  Since $\big[K(\beta):K\big]=n$ by assumption that $X^n-a$ is irred over $K$, the result follows from $\big[K(\beta):K\big]=\big[K(\beta):K(\beta^m)\big]\cdot\big[K(\beta^m):K\big]$.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool I've been thinking about it but for me is hard to see $K(\beta^{m})$ as a $K(\beta)$-vectorial space, any hint why $\big[K(\beta):K(\beta^m)\big]\leq m$?

Comment: $\beta$ is a root of $X^m-\beta^m\in K(\beta^m)[X]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x):=x^n-a$ and $g(x):=x^{\frac{n}{m}}-a$ are $\it{both}$ irreducible over $K$. Otherwise, $$g(x)=\prod_{j=1}^rh_j(x)$$ for some $r>1$ and irreducibles $h_1(x),\dots,h_r(x)\in K[x]$, which would then imply $$f(x)=g(x^m)=\prod_{j=1}^rh_j(x^m)$$ violating the fact that $f(x)$ is actually irreducible over $K$. Therefore, $g(x)$ is irreducible and $g(\beta^m)=f(\beta)=\mathbf 0$. $$\therefore [K(\beta^m):K]=\deg(g(x))=\frac{n}{m}$$.